# Javascript/Javabean: co-operation not working for counter

Tags: java, javascript, refresh, javabeans

I have to make a simple webapplication using javascript and javabeans. The actual assignment is a bit different (including dropcoordinates and such), but here's my testing file problem:

Whenever the red square is clicked, it should add 1 to the value in my javabean and output it to a textfield. It shows it correctly, but then it somehow reverts back to its original value. When I debug, it doesn't even go into my method addUp(). Second problem: when I refresh the page, it DOES go into the method, no matter if I've clicked the square or not.

Here is my code:

Website index.xhtml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>

        <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <form>
        <DIV id="move" style="width:150px;height:150px;background-color:pink;border:1px solid #999999"> &nbsp; </DIV>
        <input id="test" value="${countController.counter}" />
        <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#move").click(function(event, ui){

                  alert(${countController.counter});

            });

            $("#droppable").click(function(event, ui){

                  alert(${countController.counter});
                  ${countController.telOp()};
                  document.getElementById("test").value = ${countController.counter};

                  alert(${countController.counter});
                  //window.location.reload();


            });
            });
        </SCRIPT>

        <div id="droppable" style="width:150px;height:150px;background-color:red;border:1px solid #999999">Drop here</div>

        </form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

CountController.java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

/**
 *
 * @author Laurent
 */
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class CountController implements Serializable{

    /** Creates a new instance of countController */
    public CountController() {
    }

    private int counter = 0;

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

    public void setCounter(int counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    public void telOp(){
        counter++;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event listener in your managed bean such as

```
buttonClicked(ActionEvent event){

}
```

and then from the ui, you implement a h:commandLink or h:commandButton to invoke the action event.

Comment: Hi,

thanks for the reply, but it seems I could only use that in my test, in the end, it has to be on the ondrop action, which I don't think I can do with commandlink or commandbutton